# Cassandra: How to check if a column value is already present

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I am using Cassandra. There is a column name-text which stores all say usernames.

```
name
------
bob
Bob
bobby
mike
michael
micky
BOB
```

I have 2 questions

1. I have to select all user names that starts with 'bo'. I know there is no like equivalent in Cassandra. But is there anyway to achieve that? (Additional column is an option but is there something else?)
2. There are 3 entries. bob,Bob and BOB. Is there anyway to use fetch all 3 rows if I pass where name='bob'. I need to fetch the names case-insensitive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "But is there anyway to achieve that": there are several, of various kinds of complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the second question first.  If you want to support case-insensitive queries, you should store a second, upper-case copy of the text data you want to search for in another column.  Then by querying by that column you'll be able to do case-insensitive requests.

Going back to searches for `bo*`.  The best way to do that is to use a schema that allows you to leverage clustering columns (columns 2 and higher of the primary key) for range searches.  Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (region INT, name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (region, name));
```

In particular, if you make `name` the second column of the key, you will be able to perform searches such as

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE name >= 'bo' and name < 'bp' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

which will return results you're looking for.  This only works for trailing wildcards: the leading characters have to be constant for range queries to work.  Again, if you want to do case-insensitive searches, have the case-insensitive column be the second part of the primary key and query by it:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE name_upper >= 'BO' and name_upper < 'BP' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Comment: And 'ALLOW FILTERING' usually means 'My schema is wrong' :)

Comment: Fair enough; could you suggest a better schema for this use case?

Comment: You could have the partition key be the first letter of the target column, but then it may be somewhat awkward if you try a range query spanning letters.  On the other hand, this was not part of the question anyway, so probably this would be acceptable.

Comment: BTW, I don't think 'pure' Cassandra is a good fit for the use case at all, but Solr + Cassandra should work